# String parsing with space

Tags: java, string, split

I am reading a file where each like looks like something like this:

`EmpId:6428 EmpName:Josh Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]`

I want the `EmpId`, `EmpName` and Classes. I am splitting it by space which in turn also split the classes. So basically at the end for the list of classes, I am just getting `Classes:[Math,`. But I want the entire list of classes. Please share your advice on how can split this. Thanks

```
private static class EmpResource {
        private String empId;
        private String empName;
        private List<String> classes;

        public TableResource(final String line) {
            String[] strs = line.split(" ");
            this.empId = strs[0].split(":")[1];
            this.empName = strs[1].split(":")[1];
            String classes = strs[2].split(":")[1];
            convertToClassList(classes);
        }


        void setClasses(List<String> classes) {
            this.classes = classes;
        }


        private void convertToClassList(String classes) {

            if (!"null".equals(class)) {
                String replace = indexString.replaceAll("^\\[|]$", "");
                setIndexes(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(replace.split(", "))));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Expected Result:**

```
empId 6428
empName Josh 
List<String> classes [Math,English,Bio,Art,comp]
```

**Actual Result:**

```
empId 6428
empName Josh
List<String> classes [Math,
```

Comment: An ugly way to work around this would be to split only if the character preceding the whitespace is not a comma (you can use a negative lookbehind expression). But generally regex isn't the best solution for de-serializing hierarchical structured text.

Comment: do this before splitting line=line.replaceAll(", ",",");

Comment: `String classes = strs[2].split(":")[1];` won't work, you need to re-join every index from `2` to `strs.length - 1` first, then parse the result.

Comment: Where is the String from `convertToClassList(String classes)` coming from? Can't you just iterate over your list  `List<String> classes`? Your approach is probably way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment, a working but dirty fix to not split on your inner space-separated "classes" elements would be to make the initial split conditional to no comma preceding the white space.

For instance, you can use a negative lookbehind to split only if the whitespace isn't preceded by a comma.

**Example**

```
String test = "EmpId:6428 EmpName:Josh Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]";
System.out.println(test.split("(?<!,) ")[2]);
```

**Output**

```
Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]
```

Generally speaking though, you might want to consider implementing your own parser if the syntax gets more complicated.

Regex can only drive you so far before backfiring.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.split with a limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)).

Then you only split the line into 3 strings, so the classes will all be together in the last string.

```
String line = "EmpId:6428 EmpName:Josh Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]";
String[] strs = line.split(" ", 3);
System.out.println(strs[2]);
```

Output:

```
Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]
```

As FedericoklezCulloca pointed out in the comment, the above doesn't work if the name contains a space (e.g. first name last name). A more robust way to do it is to look for the specific labels, as in the following code which does it using a regex:

```
private static Pattern LINE_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("EmpId:(.*) EmpName:(.*) Classes:\\[(.*)\\]");

public void test() {
    String line = "EmpId:6428 EmpName:Josh Adams Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]";
    Matcher lineMatcher = LINE_PATTERN.matcher(line);
    if (lineMatcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("EmpId   = " + lineMatcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Name    = " + lineMatcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("Classes = " + lineMatcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
EmpId   = 6428
Name    = Josh Adams
Classes = Math, English, Bio, Art, comp
```

Comment: This works only if `EmpName` doesn't contain spaces. For example "Mary Jane" would break the algorithm.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that's true. The example data in the exercise shows only a single name without a space. If there is a possibility of a space in the data, a different algorithm would be needed, such as finding the last occurrence of " Classes: [" in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you know you have an empId, empName and Classes part, so why not using a single regex which matches the whole line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("EmpId:(.*) EmpName:(.*) Classes:\\[(.*)\\]");
    String input="EmpId:6428 EmpName:Josh Classes:[Math, English, Bio, Art, comp]";
    Matcher m=p.matcher(input);
    if(m.matches())
    {
        System.out.println("empId:"+m.group(1));
        System.out.println("empName"+m.group(2));
        System.out.println("Classes:"+m.group(3));
        String[] classes=m.group(3).split(", ");
        System.out.println("classes:'"+classes[1]+"'");

    } else
        System.err.println("no match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If line wasn't final, you could do `line = line.replaceAll(", ", "");`, but since it is you need a temp string.

```
String temp = String.valueOf(line.toCharArray().clone());
temp = temp.replaceAll(", ", "");
```

Then you could do whatever you did without any trouble, since there are not other spaces to interfere.

```
String[] strs = temp.split(" "); // Make sure it's temp, since temp is the one you changed.
this.empId = strs[0].split(":")[1];
this.empName = strs[1].split(":")[1];
String classes = strs[2].split(":")[1];
convertToClassList(classes);
```